# How to resolve modules with turbopack in NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, turbopack

Node APIs are not available on the client, but many NextJS projects have nested dependencies to these APIs (i.e. `fs`). With webpack it's easy to adjust how the module resolves based on client/server environment, but it's unclear how to do so with turbopack.

Is there a turbopack workaround like the webpack one below?

```
webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
    }
    return config;
  },
```